# How to introduce perpendicular or congruence of angles in affine space

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$n$-dimensional affine point-vector space is a pair $\mathbb A^n = \langle \mathbb A, V^n \rangle$, where $\mathbb A$ is an arbitrary set, which elements are called points of affine space, $V^n$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector space together with function $\mathbb A \times \mathbb A \to V^n$, denoted $(A,B)\mapsto \vec{AB}$, such that the following axioms hold:

1. $\vec{AB}+\vec{BC} = \vec{AC}$ for any $A,B,C \in \mathbb A$,
2. For any $A \in \mathbb A$ and for any $r \in V^n$ there exists a unique $B \in \mathbb A$ such that $\vec{AB} = r$.

In my book it is written that $\mathbb A^3$ is a simpliest model of our physical space (Golubev, Foundations of theoretical mechanics). Then author uses such notions as "two lines are perpendicular". My question is how to introduce a perpendicular in affine space? Hilbert in his Foundations of Geometry introduce a notion of right angle as the angle that is congruent to its complement. Then two lines are perpendicular if their intersection provide us four right angles. What is the way to introduce relation of congruence of angles in affine space then?

Comment: You cannot define angles in affine space, in the sense that this is impossible to do in a way invariant under the affine group.

Comment: Hilbert is able to do what he does because his constraints are simpler: his notion of angle need only be invariant under the euclidian group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez hm? Why I can't, for example, introduce a scalar product in $V^n$ and then measure angle between lines $AB$ and $AC$ as $\mathop{\mathrm{arccos}} \frac{\langle \vec{AB}, \vec{AC} \rangle}{|\vec{AB}| |\vec{AC}|}$?

Comment: No scalar product is invariant under the affine group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez There is nothing said about the action of affine group in my book. If I introduce such notion of angle, what will happen? Axioms I've written in my post will be inconsistent or what? As I remember school level geometry, all axioms from my post worked well for the space we considered

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I can write more from book. Author introduces an arbitrary scalar product in $V^n$ and then introduces the euclidean metric in $\mathbb A$ as $\rho(A,B) = \sqrt{ \langle \vec{AB}, \vec{AB} \rangle }$. Then he calls the affine space $\mathbb A^n$ with introduced euclidean metric the euclidean space $\mathbb E^n$. Then he says that in $\mathbb A^3$ which is the simpliest model of the real physical space we can introduce orthogonality using the notion of perpendicularity (so there is a special way to introduce scalar product).

Comment: technically the «affine space» is the study of things built on the affine space which are invariant under the action of the affine group, just as euclidean geometry is the study of things which are invariant under the group of euclidean motions. If you are talking about «affine spaces» as just a synomyn for vector space (as you seem to be doing) then, well, things are different.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes, I think that it is the easiest way to obtain something that behaves like vector space but without any fixed point